# PHP in Google App Engine, how to detect the url of the incoming redirect?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, url, redirect

I am not sure if this is possible but was wondering if we can detect the url from where `header('Location: ')` initiated.

I have a couple of scripts with `header('Location: /main.php')` and now when main.php is executed I want to find out from which script or URL did the redirect initiate from.

```
script.php
header('Location: /main.php');

main.php
//detect the source url.. ie /script.php or website.com/script.php
// do some action
header('location: /script.php');
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this on main.php.

```
$referer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Comment: I would assume it should work in normal server. But I keep getting this error.

`Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER`

Which seems odd. I wonder if there is something different for running the website in google app engine.

Comment: That error mostly occurs when the HTTP_REFERER is null.. You could use a code like `if(isset($var))` or `if($var <> null)` with var being `$_SERVER["HTT_REFERER"]`  But I'm not sure if that would work in your scenario even still.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work for me with the following code

```
script.php
$document = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$fullPath = $host.$document;
setcookie('referer', $fullPath,time()+86400); // cookie is destroyed on redirect
header('Location: /main.php?referer='.$fullPath);
```

and the other one is as below

```
main.php
$referer = $_REQUEST['referer'];
if($referer != null){
        header("location: http://".urldecode($referer));
    }
```

The cookie I set got deleted when `main.php` was executed, hence I had to send the info over via POST. 
Also I had to use urldecode on $referrer.

This may not be the best way to do this but it worked for and if any one can improve this I would be happy to learn from it.